# I want to use my ASP.NET Core project with my own angular project

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6BEn.png)

I have a project where I send a request to an API and see the data I get from there with the Swagger interface and save them to a database. But I want to see this with the Angular project that I want to create, not with Swagger.

I haven't tried anything yet. I know how to create an Angular project. It would be nice if you could suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First of all, you would need to have a component class in angular which will call the http request to your Web API endpoint, in addition to this, within that component, you should have method/function for calling that API endpoint like this `this.http.request(yourBaseURL + '/api/YourAPIControllerName/ActionName')`, while implementing, if you face any issue, just post relevant question that would be easy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Set up the Angular Project:

   - Make sure you have Node.js and Angular CLI installed on your machine.
   - Open your terminal and create a new Angular project using the Angular CLI command: `ng new your-project-name`
   - Navigate to the project directory: `cd your-project-name`
2. Create Angular Components:

   - Use the Angular CLI to generate components to display and manipulate data. For example, if you're working on a project to display products, you can create a component named "ProductListComponent" using: `ng generate component product-list`
   - Similarly, create other components as per your requirements.
3. Set up API Integration:

   - Determine the API endpoints you need to interact with to fetch data. Make sure the API is running and accessible.
   - In your Angular project, create a service to handle API requests. Use the Angular HTTP client to send HTTP requests and receive responses from the API. You can generate a service with: `ng generate service api`
   - Inside the service, implement methods to interact with the API using methods like `get()`, `post()`, `put()`, `delete()`, etc.
   - Inject the created service in the components where you want to fetch data from the API.
4. Display Data in Components:

   - In your components, use the services you created to fetch data from the API.
   - Display the data in the component's template using Angular's data binding and interpolation features.
5. Store Data in the Database:

   - To save data to a database, you'll need a backend server with a database system. You can use technologies like Node.js, Express.js, and a database like MongoDB.
   - Create API endpoints on the backend to handle requests for data storage (e.g., POST requests to save new data).
   - Modify your Angular service to also include methods to send data to these backend endpoints.
6. Form Submission:

   - If you want to allow users to submit data through forms and save it to the database, create Angular forms using Angular's FormBuilder and ReactiveFormsModule.
   - When users submit the form, send the form data to the backend API using your Angular service.
7. Authentication (Optional):

   - If your API requires authentication, you can implement authentication mechanisms in your Angular project. Use technologies like JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for token-based authentication.
8. Error Handling and Validation:

   - Implement error handling and validation to provide a better user experience. Handle API errors gracefully and display appropriate messages to users.
9. Deployment:

   - Once your Angular project is complete, you can build and deploy it to a server or a hosting platform of your choice.

Remember that these are general steps, and the implementation details may vary depending on the specific API and database you are using. It's essential to refer to the documentation of the API and the database system you want to work with.

Good luck with your project, and feel free to ask if you have any specific questions along the way!